# Minecraft 1.8 Function Namesin 1.8.8?

Tags: java, function, minecraft

I coded a client in the 1.8.8 and now I wanted to insert something from an older client of mine into the client but these are made in the 1.8 and most of the functions are called func_123456_a something like that and in the 1.8.8 these functions have a real name I wanted to know if there is a kind of list where you can see what 1.8 funcs are called in the 1.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip.file "**mcp_stable-18-1.8.zip**" from here: http://export.mcpbot.bspk.rs/stable/?page=2 , and open **methods.csv**.

There you can find names for all the functions.

You can search for these names in your 1.8.8 list (methods.csv), located in your Client fodlder under \conf, assuming you used MCP.